# Bluetooth Tutorial Error Wrong Libraries?

Tags: android, c++, bluetooth, winsock

I want to learn how to connect Bluetooth devices to my laptop and get information from them via C++. I kept running across the tutorial [here](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedotherprotocol4k.html) online, so I thought I'd try to get it going to see how different stuff works.

Here is the code:

```
// If you have 1 or more bluetooth dongles attached to the system.
// this will select the first one, then it will perform a scan for
// all devices within range of that dongle and print out all the
// information available about each device. then move on to the next
// dongle and repeat the process, etc. doesn't actually DO much apart
// from find devices and display their information.

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Link to ws2_32.lib
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2bth.h>

// Link to Bthprops.lib
#include <BluetoothAPIs.h>

BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS m_bt_find_radio = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS) };
BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO m_bt_info = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_RADIO_INFO), 0, };
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS m_search_params = {
    sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS),
    1,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    1,
    15,
    NULL
};
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO m_device_info = { sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO), 0, };

// Note:
// Radio - is the thing plugged in/attached to the local machine.
// Device - is the thing that is connected to via the Bluetooth connection.
int main(int argc, char **args)
{
    HANDLE m_radio = NULL;
    HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND m_bt = NULL;
    HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND m_bt_dev = NULL;
    int m_radio_id;
    int m_device_id;
    DWORD mbtinfo_ret;

    // Iterate for available bluetooth radio devices in range
    // Starting from the local

    while (TRUE)
    {
        m_bt = BluetoothFindFirstRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio);
        if (m_bt != NULL)
            printf("BluetoothFindFirstRadio() is OK!\n");
        else
            printf("BluetoothFindFirstRadio() failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        m_radio_id = 0;
        do {
            // Then get the radio device info....
            mbtinfo_ret = BluetoothGetRadioInfo(m_radio, &m_bt_info);
            if (mbtinfo_ret == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                printf("BluetoothGetRadioInfo() looks fine!\n");
            else
                printf("BluetoothGetRadioInfo() failed wit herror code %d\n", mbtinfo_ret);
            wprintf(L"Radio %d:\r\n", m_radio_id);
            wprintf(L"\tInstance Name: %s\r\n", m_bt_info.szName);
            wprintf(L"\tAddress: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\r\n", m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[5],
                m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[4], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[3], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[2],
                m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[1], m_bt_info.address.rgBytes[0]);
            wprintf(L"\tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_bt_info.ulClassofDevice);
            wprintf(L"\tManufacturer: 0x%04x\r\n", m_bt_info.manufacturer);
            m_search_params.hRadio = m_radio;
            ZeroMemory(&m_device_info, sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO));
            m_device_info.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO);
            // Next for every radio, get the device
            m_bt_dev = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&m_search_params, &m_device_info);
            if (m_bt_dev != NULL)
                printf("\nBluetoothFindFirstDevice() is working!\n");
            else
                printf("\nBluetoothFindFirstDevice() failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
            m_radio_id++;
            m_device_id = 0;
            // Get the device info
            do
            {
                wprintf(L"\n\tDevice %d:\r\n", m_device_id);
                wprintf(L"  \tInstance Name: %s\r\n", m_device_info.szName);
                wprintf(L"  \tAddress: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\r\n", m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[5],
                    m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[4], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[3], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[2],
                    m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[1], m_device_info.Address.rgBytes[0]);
                wprintf(L"  \tClass: 0x%08x\r\n", m_device_info.ulClassofDevice);
                wprintf(L"  \tConnected: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fConnected ? L"true" : L"false");
                wprintf(L"  \tAuthenticated: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fAuthenticated ? L"true" : L"false");
                wprintf(L"  \tRemembered: %s\r\n", m_device_info.fRemembered ? L"true" : L"false");
                m_device_id++;
                // Well, the found device information can be used for further socket
                // operation such as creating a socket, bind, listen, connect, send, receive etc..
                // If no more device, exit the loop
                if (!BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info))
                    break;
            } while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(m_bt_dev, &m_device_info));
            // NO more device, close the device handle
            if (BluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) == TRUE)
                printf("\nBluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) is OK!\n");
            else
                printf("\nBluetoothFindDeviceClose(m_bt_dev) failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        } while (BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio));
        // No more radio, close the radio handle
        if (BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) == TRUE)
            printf("BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) is OK!\n");
        else
            printf("BluetoothFindRadioClose(m_bt) failed with error code %d\n", GetLastError());
        // Exit the outermost WHILE and BluetoothFindXXXXRadio loops if there is no more radio
        if (!BluetoothFindNextRadio(&m_bt_find_radio, &m_radio))
            break;
        // Give some time for the 'signal' which is a typical for crap wireless devices
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build and run the program, I get the following errors:

[image]

I can't figure out where the unresolved external errors are coming from. I read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix?rq=1)) that they usually come from having something declared but not initialized properly. I thought it possibly had something to do with needing to add the Winsock header files to my project, so I found the Winsock2 and Ws2bth header files and added them to my project but that didn't work either.

Then I thought it could be a library issue, so I went online to see if I could download Winsock libraries, but I could only find downloads for WinsockFix.

I am new to Bluetooth and Winsock. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this whole setup and how I can fix it?

Note: I am using Visual Studio 2013 and trying to connect an Android phone to my laptop.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your stdafx.cpp or in the main code. It should work.

#pragma comment(lib, "bthprops.lib")